# Unable to paste sms code to PinFieldAutoFill (sms_autofill package)

Tags: flutter, sms

I want my users to have the ability to paste their code manually, to the `PinFieldAutoFill` pincode field, of the [sms_autofill](https://pub.dev/packages/sms_autofill) package, in case the autofill is not working.

Pasting is not working for that pin field.

Here is my code:

```
PinFieldAutoFill(
        autoFocus: autoFocus,
        currentCode: autoComplete ? smsCode : null,
        decoration: BoxLooseDecoration(
          strokeColorBuilder: const FixedColorBuilder(Color(0xFFE6E6E6)),
          bgColorBuilder: const FixedColorBuilder(Color(0xFFE6E6E6)),
          strokeWidth: 1.2,
        ),
        onCodeChanged: (p0) {
          ...
        },
      )
```